# Julia, run function multiple times, save results in array

Tags: function, parallel-processing, julia, map-function, pmap

I am building a microsimulation model in Julia.  I have built the structure of my function and it runs great for for 1 "person". I'd like to write the script to run 100000+ people through the model and save the results in one location.

Eventually I'd like to execute this in parallel.

Below I have included a simple working version of the code with dummy probabilities.

```
using Distributions

# Microsim function
function  MicroSim(start_age, stages)
  stage = 0
  age = start_age

  # Set all trackers to 0
  Death_tracker = 0
  Disease_tracker = 0

  # While loop
  while stage <= stages
    age = age

    ###########################################################
    # Probability of Death
    pD = 0.02

    if age == 100
      pD = 1.0
    else
      pD = pD
    end

    # Coin flip
    dist_pD = Bernoulli(pD)
    Died = rand(dist_pD, 1)

    if Died == [1]
      Death_tracker = 1
      # death tracker loop break
      if Death_tracker == 1
        # println("I died")
        break
      end
    else
      Death_tracker = Death_tracker
    end
    ###########################################################

  # Update age and stage
  age = age + 1
  stage = stage + 1

  end

return age, Death_tracker

end


MicroSim(18,100)
```

Comment: can't you loop the function many times? `for i in 1:100 println(MicroSim(18,100)) end`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the functions `map` and `pmap` (for parallelization).  I've simplified your function to give a more minimal working example. (in the future, please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on creating such minimal examples in your questions).

`map` takes a function (that you specify) and applies it to all of the elements in an array.  If your function takes multiple arguments (as yours does), then you simply feed `map` multiple successive arrays.  `map` then returns a new array with the results of all your functions.

```
function MicroSim(start_age, stages)
    return rand(start_age), rand(stages)
end

Start_Ages = [10, 20, 15]
Stages = [1, 4, 5]

Results = map(MicroSim, Start_Ages, Stages)
```

If you want to parallelize things, there are just three simple adjustments.  1. use the `addprocs()` function to add however many additional processes you want.  2. use the `@everywhere` macro when declaring your function so that your worker processes also have access to it.  3. use the function `pmap` instead of `map`:

```
addprocs(2)

@everywhere begin
    function MicroSim(start_age, stages)
        return rand(start_age), rand(stages)
    end
end

Results = pmap(MicroSim, Start_Ages, Stages)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The map function is applying the correct elements and producing results, but everything is being stored in a vector where each element is a tuple. Is there any easy way to convert this to an array?

Comment: @MJH Right now, your function is outputting a tuple.  If you put brackets around your return value then it will output an array.  Then, you can use `BigArray = vcat(results...)` to turn it into a single array, one row for each run of your simulation.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge That's perfect. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou  Potentially.  It doesn't hurt to try it out and do some speed tests.  Generally, vectorization doesn't do so well performance wise in Julia, but there are always exceptions.